# what does someclass.__init__ thing do

Tags: python, class, object

```
class subclass(superclass):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        superclass.__init__(self, blah1, blah2)
```

What is the purpose of using `superclass.__init__(self, blah1, blah2)`?
I am a little confused regarding whether to use the last line or not while inheriting a superclass.

Comment: Any specific programming language?

Comment: Depends on the superclass. It may very well do nothing at all.

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101214203620AAooELF

Comment: @GolezTrol The language I am talking about is Python.

Comment: Yes, it depends on whether the superclass's `__init__()` function does something you want to do.

Comment: passing `self` to `__init__` of superclass would not be needed [ wrong, even ] as it gets passed implicitly.

Comment: @ersran9 You're wrong.

Comment: @Marcin could you elaborate?

Comment: In my opinion superclass's `__init__` is used to define arguments which are to defined as same as in superclass. Am I right? Further what is the use of `class subclass(superclass)` exactly. I mean what things does subclass inherit from superclass using this? Does it inherit function, arguments or what?

Comment: you should read http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html - that should cover most of your questions.

Comment: @ersran9 Ok... I am reading it.

Comment: @ersran9: You have to explicitly pass `self` to a base class constructor, see: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thank you for taking time to link it - clearly I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
superclass.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

is essentially equivelent to

```
super(Myclass,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

that is it calls the supers constructor. but it skips the rest of the inheritance stack (I think `super()` bubbles  or something... most of the time i use the first method)

**this is probably an over simplification